# Tangent Line problem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The line $y=\frac{-1}{2}x+\frac{9}{2}$ is tangent to the curve y=$\frac{ax}{x-1}$, find $a$ $\in \mathbb{R} $ and the points where $y$ is tangent to the curve.

Solution:

$1.)a = 2,P=(3,3)$,

$2.)a=8,P=(-3,6)$

I have been stuck on this problem for two hours and i cant solve it i looked up similar problems on here but I still cant slove it.

Comment: Hint: Use the limit definition of a derivative.

Comment: Well, where exactly are you getting stuck? Show your work up to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the derivative of $y=\frac {ax}{x-1}$ gives $$\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {ax-a-ax} {(x-1)^2} = -\frac a {(x-1)^2}$$.
Thus the point whose slope is $-\frac 1 2$ is $$-\frac 1 2 = -\frac a {(x-1)^2}$$, which gives $x_{1,2}=1\pm\sqrt{2a}$.
Plug $x$ into the expression $y=\frac{-1}{2}x+\frac{9}{2}$ gives $y_{1,2}=\frac {\sqrt{2a}\mp1+9} 2$. Now try to find which $a$ lets $(x,y)$ be on the curve $y=\frac {ax}{x-1}$. To do that, plug $x$ into the curve and calculate $y'$, and compare $y$ and $y'$.